# MOQ Creating a Mock of an abstract class returns null

Tags: c#, nunit, tdd, moq

Firstly, I understand that the title of my question doesn't really suit the question; I just wasn't sure what the title should've been.

It is to the best of my knowledge that when creating a mock of an abstract class with MOQ if the creation of the object fails (due to exception handling or something else) the creation of the mock will simply return null.

In my case, I wish to check if an `ArgumentNullException` has been thrown within the constructor. But instead my test fails due to what I've stated above and the actual result is `null`, not `ArgumentNullException`

```cs
public abstract class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(ISomeDependency someDependency)
    {
        if (someDependency == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(someDependency));
        }

        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }
}
```

```cs
public sealed class LogHandlerTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Constructor_Test_Should_Throw_ArgumentNulLException_When_SomeDependency_Is_Null()
    {
            Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => new Mock<SomeClass>(null));
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you meant to use `new Mock<SomeClass>(null).Object` instead of `new Mock<SomeClass>(null)`?

Comment: @nalka I need to check if the constructor through the exception, therefore I have to assert the creation of said object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `new Mock<SomeClass>(null)` you want to use `new Mock<SomeClass>(null).Object` because the constructor is only invoked the first time you use the mocked object. You'll then end up having a `TargetInvocationException` because Moq uses reflection to achieve Mocking. This means you probably need a code similar to

```
[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        Exception caughtException = null;
        try
        {
            var test = new Mock<SomeClass>(null).Object;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            caughtException = ex;
        }

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(caughtException.InnerException, typeof(ArgumentNullException));
    }
}

public abstract class SomeClass
{
    ISomeDependency someDependency;

    public SomeClass(ISomeDependency someDependency)
    {
        if (someDependency == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(someDependency));
        }

        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No real need to use MOQ here.

Sometimes it helps to keep it simple and create a derived class to satisfy the desired behavior.

For example

```
public sealed class LogHandlerTests {

    private class Subject: SomeClass {
        public Subject(): base (null) { //<-- SHOULD THROW
            //...
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Constructor_Test_Should_Throw_ArgumentNulLException_When_SomeDependency_Is_Null() {
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => new Subject());
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I didn't approve your answer is only because this question is specifically talking about how to accomplish this task with MOQ. But I do want you to know, that I've decided to go this route.

Comment: @SleepyTurtle the choice is yours. Once you found a solution.

Comment: @SleepyTurtle if you found the answer helpful then an up-vote is fine.